# Interface literals in Go

Tags: go, interface, literals, composite

First to clarify the title, I know there is no such thing as interface literals in Go but I couldn't come up with another name for this issue.

I was reading some Go code and found a weird construct, like so:

```
clientOptions := []grpc.DialOption{grpc.WithInsecure()}
cc, err := grpc.Dial(l.Addr().String(), clientOptions...)
```

Here grpc.DialOptions is an interface type and grpc.WithInsecure() returns that type. What caught my eye here is that clientOptions is a slice, which seemed redundant to me. So I tried to remove the braces like so:

```
clientOptions := grpc.DialOption{grpc.WithInsecure()}
```

But I get compilation error: "invalid composite literal type grpc.DialOption"

I tried to simulate this on the go playground and I get the same result.
This code runs fine:
https://go.dev/play/p/QJQR9BDGN4a

But this version fails with the same "invalid composite literal type error":
https://go.dev/play/p/A0FasDybUg5

Can someone explain this?
Thanks

Comment: `clientOptions` is slice because the type is inferred from a slice literal expression.  The `[]` in the composite literal indicates that the literal is a slice. The simplification is to create the slice implicitly using the variadic argument mechanism:  `cc, err := grpc.Dial(l.Addr().String(),grpc.WithInsecure())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that this creates a slice:

```
clientOptions := []grpc.DialOption{grpc.WithInsecure()}
```

But I think you've misunderstood which syntax does what. This would be an empty slice literal:

```
clientOptions := []grpc.DialOption{}
```

This would be a single value, not in a slice:

```
clientOptions := grpc.WithInsecure()
```

For reference, this syntax is covered in the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/).

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Although I still don't understand why the author of the code chose that syntax. I tried to change to code like this:
`clientOption := grpc.WithInsecure()`
`cc, err := grpc.Dial(l.Addr().String(), clientOption)`
And everything works correctly. I don't understand the point of creating a slice if you only need a single value.